# How can I get objects directly from Google Maps, not Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get coordinates of a map object (gate in the airport).

I can't do it with the Places API, because gates are not Places objects.

If you open maps.google.com and type SFO Gate 27 it doesn't find it, but if you type SFO, press Enter and then type Gate 27, you'll get the right place.

So, my question is how to find such places with JS SDK or HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with the geocoder.

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10)
    });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // Bind click event listener for search button
    document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('click', codeAddress, false);

    // Bind key-up event listener for address field
    document.getElementById("address").addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

        // Check the event key code
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            // Key code 13 == Enter key was pressed (and released)
            codeAddress();
        }
    });
}

function codeAddress() {

    // Get address and geocode
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            // Center map on result bounds
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);

            // Place marker on map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qeswb2v0/)</kbd>